# How do I find the right Stack Exchange site to post on?

Tags: discussion, support, asking-questions, site-recommendation, user-experience

I'm new to Stack Exchange and I have a question to ask. I arrived at the main homepage and couldn't see any list of sub-sites, just a list of random questions.

Then I noticed a button saying "Learn more", which took me to a page called "Tour", at the bottom of which was another button saying "See all sites". I clicked on this, not sure what to expect, and found what appeared to be a "list" of all the different sub-sites, though no page title was given, so this is a guess.

My question concerns computer software, so I clicked "Technology", but there's still about 100 different sites.

Presumably, users can't reasonably be expected to read through all 100 site titles? Especially since:

1. They're not organized into any sub-categories
2. Most of them have esoteric, non-descriptive names like "Super User" "Ask Different" and "Tex LaTeX"
3. They're not laid out in an easy-to-read list, but in a haphazard arrangement of rectangles, which is totally contrary to quickly skimming through a list of titles.

So, my question is, how is anyone (particularly new users) reasonably expected to find the correct sub-site to post their question in?

Comment: Click ask a question and then tag it with appropriate tags. There's no strict subforum structure (which is a good thing; most programming questions will touch on math stuff, shell stuff, and on the programming language stuff - this way you can tag it with everything relevant instead of picking one).

Comment: I don't see any button on the homepage to ask a question. Can anyone tell me how to get to it from the homepage please?

Comment: Also, if you can post questions about any subject without having to go into the relevant sub-forum (which sounds ideal) then why is there a prohibitively strict sign-up process involved in the "Server Fault" community? I tried posting there but it required me to spend literally hours of my life reading terms and conditions. Who would ever do that if they could post questions on any topic without signing up to the sub-communities?

Comment: I think this is a legit question, the Stack Exchange network has outgrown the simple categorisation currently in use.

Comment: People generally find out which sites are relevant to them by searching for existing answers. If there is one thing that Stack Exchanges expects you to do, it is to search before asking. You will find existing questions and answers, almost guaranteed. They may not work for you, you may not understand them, but they will at least be contextually relevant to you. The site those questions are asked in, are the sites you will be looking for to ask your own questions in.

Comment: We should create a community wiki answer that would be a big flowchart leading to each site's `on-topic` page. This would require a lot of work and frequent updates, but it would help a lot of people who come on the site I moderate because they have no idea where else to post. Of course, one of the flowchart's end will be "*There is no site where your question is on-topic, try other Internet forums*".

Answer (score 6):

Go to the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) of a site that looks relevant and read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

It would also be worthwhile browsing some relevant [tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tags) to see [what type of questions are being posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript?tab=Active) and which are receiving upvotes and answers and which are not. This will also give you a feel to what is expected on the site.

You can also browse questions on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) for each site, to see what is [on topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scope) for each site.

[image]

You're over half way there. You've read the tour and now you're asking what to do.

Answer (score 5):

It seems, in between the situation has improved: from the bottom of each page here on the site, you get by two clicks to a [list of all sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#traffic), which now has the kind of layout you asked for:

- an easy-to-read list
- each entry with a short description of the site's main topics
- filterable into sub categories

The "grid arrangement" of all sites is [still available](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=grid), but I share your critics - this is barely useful to find a specific site when you have a topic in mind and don't know which SE site could be a match for it.

Especially for computer science / programming related questions, one can also use [this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-sites-do-i-post-on) as an orientation guide, which may be found through the [SE FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites) - but I admit, that may not be the most obvious thing to find for newbies.